# Create new Date() object with setDate tomorrow (+1) and setHours(0,0,0,0) in one expression

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to create a new `Date` object with `setDate()` for tomorrow using +1 and setHours(0,0,0,0) in one expression, is it possible? I'm able to do both create object and setDate tomorrow but missing the last part setHours(0,0,0,0).

```
//Create Date object and setDate to tomorrow as below

new Date((new Date).setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1))
```

Comment: `new Date(new Date((new Date).setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1)).setHours(0,0,0,0))` as extension to your snippet, but I am sure there must be some shorter and efficient way.

Comment: Why do you want to achieve in one expression? Two lines for setting date and hours are fine...

Comment: `new Date(new Date(new Date().getTime()+86400000).setHours(0,0,0,0))`

Comment: @SarjanDesai using it in a specific mongo query which doesn't allow for several lines.

Comment: @vinayakj Thanks! Worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved fast. Thanks @vinayakj for great help!

Solution

```
new Date(new Date(new Date().getTime()+86400000).setHours(0,0,0,0))
```

Answer (score 3):

Technically one expression:

```
var a = (
    function (d) {
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
        d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        return d;
    }(new Date())
);
```

One-liner, but error-prone when the date changes just between evaluating two parameters:

```
var a = new Date(1900 + new Date().getYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate() + 1);
```

Comment: I assume it would work but not in my mongo query where I'm using it unfortunately. Thanks for the help tho :) much appreciated!